# Internal CSS style heading

Tags: html, css, styles

So this is my first html code and I'm having trouble with the internal style of the h1 heading although I wrote body style after h1 and it works fine and i removed all the inline styles in heading. Could someone tell me where the problem is ??

```html
<head>
<style>
  h1{
  color: DarkCyan !important; 
  border: 10px solid crimson !important;
  font-family: courier !important; 
  text-align: center !important;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>  
  <h1> My First trial of a site </h1>
</body>
```

This is the whole code as when i ran this code snippet above it on jsfiddle it worked fine but the whole code didn't show the styling.(If it is not okay to post the whole code please tell me to delete it as I'm a newbie here.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title> 

   Page title 

</title>
<style> <!-- Internal CSS style-->

    h1{
        color: DarkCyan !important; 
        border: 10px solid crimson !important;
        font-family: courier !important; 
        text-align: center !important;
       }
    body{
        color: #8e0035;
        background-color: Beige; 
        font-family:verdana;
        }

    a:link{
        color:Purple;
        text-decoration: transparent;
    }

    a:visited{
        color:grey;
        text-decoration: transparent;
    }
    a:hover{
        color: green;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1> My First trial of a site </h1>
  <hr>
  <p title = "Hover over the paragraph one more time!" style="color: 
black;"><a href="https://www.sololearn.com target="_blank""> This link will 
take you to sololearn site <br/> with a link anchored to it </a></p>
  <img src="download (6).jpg" alt="An image here">
  <hr>
  <pre> <!-- font family in body doean't apply here -->
  The preformatted tag

  will preserve line breaks    and spaces.
  </pre>
  <hr>

  <!-- Formatting of text -->

  <h3>Formatting of text:</h3>
  <ul>
  <li><b>Bold</b></li>
  <li><strong>Strong</strong></li>
  <li><i>Italic</i></li>
  <li><em>Emphasized</em></li>
  <li><mark>Marked</mark></li>
  <li><small>Small</small></li>
  <li><del>Deleted</del></li>
  <li><ins>Inserted</ins></li>
  <li><sub>Subscrpted</sub>text</li>
  <li><sup>Superscripted</sup>text</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>

  <h3>Quotations forms:</h3>
  <p><ins>Small Quote:</ins><q>This one here with double quotes</q></p>
  <p><ins>Block quote:</ins><blockquote>This is a large quote with 
indentation</blockquote></p>
  <p>This word here "<abbr title="Laughing Out Loud">LOL</abbr>" is written 
using abbreviation. </p>
  <p><bdo dir="rtl">This text will be written from right to left.</bdo>(Bi-
directional override)</p>
  <p style="border: 1px solid crimson;"> This is a bordered Paragraph. </p> 
<!--Inline CSS style-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about you tell is _what_ the problem is first? Please go read [ask], and also how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? This: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgGdGO ?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the examples at the bottom of this "HTML <h1> to <h6> Tags" (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp) page. It will show most browser's default for H1/H6 tags.

Comment: Okay sorry for bad editing , first post on the site. But the problem is the styling doesn't appear in my browser when i open the .html file. I just noticed that it worked fine here but why no changes happen in browser ??

Comment: Myabe a cache problem. Try CTRL+F5

Comment: Tried it Didn't work. Not a cache problem i guess.

Comment: what is html code,css code exatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> comments in css use of `/*   */` no `<!--   -->`.

**Change :**

```
<style> <!-- Internal CSS style-->
```

**To:**

```
<style> /* Internal CSS style */
```

Comment: I did that in fact that was the initial code without the !important in all h1 style code but i put it just in case anything was overriding it but it didn't work either.I feel like it is a small thing but i can't put my hands on it.

Comment: Yeah it works here but not in jsfiddle or in browser.But thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: It worked when i made an external CSS stylesheet so i guess i'll stick to that all the time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NouranSamy , Change your code like update answer,see work well?

Comment: Yeah it finally worked :D But isn't this the comment syntax of java not html ?? why did it work here ?!!

Comment: @NouranSamy , you inserted  comment after  `style` with mistake syntax.see your post that you sent.

Comment: I did but not shown as my reputation below 15 but recorded (y)

Answer (score 0):

what browser are you trying to open your code in and what application are you using to edit your code?

That should work fine but try adding this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1{
color: DarkCyan !important; 
border: 10px solid crimson !important;
font-family: courier !important; 
text-align: center !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>  
<h1> My First trial of a site </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Google chrome and Notepad as a text editor because i just want to explore html before downloading any specific text editors for it. And that's exactly what i wrote in my editor for heading and also changed browser but still nothing.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I see why you had the problem now... I'd suggest downloading a text editor, my choice is "atom". Once you get your head round the basics I'd suggest downloading some free css and website templates and editing the styling and code. This is a great way to learn :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll do that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code works in js fiddle see: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5ue1p3or/

```
<head>
<style>
h1{
color: DarkCyan !important; 
border: 10px solid crimson !important;
font-family: courier !important; 
text-align: center !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>  
<h1> My First trial of a site </h1>
</body>
```

However you should use external css file for styling and try not use !important when you are not force to, as there are some basics rules to follow.
Also always remember to put doctype declaration and remember to refresh your browser after changing in css files.